# Is ascended gear worth the effort?

Tags: guild-wars-2

Take the following situation:
You have a level 80 char,  equipped with an exotic armor, exotic weapons, ascended trinkets, and a exotic back-piece. Everything has runes or sigils.

Should I now get an ascended armor and weapons? Or is there any other way to improve my character from now on by any other action? Is there a less costly (time- and gold-wise) method of improving my character further? Are there any other steps, which can be taken aside from getting more ascended gear to improve my char? 
By improve I mean stat-wise. Not improving my reputation or prestige, setting up a task for myself, etc.

Would for example leveling professions like chief and artificer, to get potions and food be more useful to boost my stats? Is this more time-intensive than a ascended gear (to gather resources, craft them), if I want to have a steady supply of those consumables?

But to get back to the point, is crafting ascended armor (and weapons) worth the effort to improve my char, since it is the only way of improving him further?

And please let me state, what I am **not** asking for:

- What ascended gear is
- The difference between any other gear and ascended gear
- How to get ascended gear

Comment: The way your question is worded, it looks like a case of "primarily opinion-based". I think that's not what you mean, so you should probably edit it to sound more analytical and requesting an answer that can be right or wrong instead of an opinion or recommendation.

Comment: @scenia I'd like to know if the question is now "better" in a way of asking for a yes/no or more concrete answer

Comment: Much better! This should induce more accurate answers now.

Comment: You can further improve your character by unlocking all available skills, but that will only improve versatility and not stats.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Should I now get an ascended armor and weapons?**
If you want to.

**Or is there any other way to improve my character from now on by any other action?**
No. Improving your actual stats will require ascended gear.

**Is there a less costly (time- and gold-wise) method of improving my character further?**
No.

**Are there any other steps, which can be taken aside from getting more ascended gear to improve my char?**
No.

**Would for example leveling professions like chief and artificer, to get potions and food be more useful to boost my stats?**
Mastering a crafting profession has no impact on your characters stats.

**Is crafting ascended armor (and weapons) worth the effort to improve my char**
I don't think so, but that's just my opinion.

Comment: It seems as I should edit my question, to clarify the point of it.

Comment: Okay thanks a lot for the updated answer, I would only disagree with point 5, since my I meant to raise my stats by **using** the consumables of those profession, not by the profession itself.

Comment: You could just buy them off the TP, though.

Comment: @VaelVictus That's true, but the point of the question(for me at least) was the comparison of the stat increase of ascended armor vs consumables

Comment: Using corresponding potions is always recommended if you have them. It doesn't take much to get some though - it's not like you have to decide "ascended or potions", you could do one, both, or neither.

Answer (score 10):

You're in the position that I was in before I went to crafting ascended gear. Simply ascended **weaponry** gives a very noticeable boost. The stat boosts are decent, remember to include the infusion in your math. If dual-wielding, you'll find your main hand weapon is likely worth the most, as those skills more often tend to do damage and there are three of them. If two-handed, even better. If you're looking for so-very-obvious efficacy-to-cost ratio, ascended weapons will do it. **Note:** I was lucky: axe/dagger means only one craft to get each. I would not go through all that again just to upgrade my staff. You may be running two weapons of different crafts, and that will bite. (or you are luckily using a two-hander)

**Ascended armor** is nice, but for the cost in gold, *at least as far as light armor goes*, run the math before you make a decision. My pants stand to cost my light-armor about 75-85g alone for a boost that is not much compared to either of my weapons. As of this writing, a Bolt of Damask is going for 12.5g on buy order.

Ultimately, a fully ascended character vs. fully exotic character (no asc. trinkets) is the difference of night and day for min/maxers. I asked myself what else I would do with the gold, if I really didn't want ascended armor? A furniture tonic and fused skin - the former 50g and the latter 225g for a single skin. Stat boosts win out for me, but perhaps they do not for you. I got the furniture tonic, love it, and am now working my way to full ascended armor.

Comment: Very nice answer, thanks for pointing out the usefulness of ascended weapons vs armor. I will head out for them first, and since I plan on gathering the resources, I will see if it takes too much time to go for an armor then.

Comment: Factor in, as well, that anything that helps you kill faster is usually preferred in MMOs, especially GW2. At the end of the day, we want to complete dungeons as fast as possible and do enough damage on world bosses before their timers run out. There is extra value in that, and much of GW2 is skill-based enough that you can survive as long as you don't stand in red circles and dodge a boss's telegraphs.

Answer (score 3):

**Should I now get an ascended armor and weapons?**
At this point and time, it s about wether you want to sink more **Time/Gold** into the game
it took me a month to finish weapon smithing and at this this half a month to get armor smithing to 400. the total cost of getting trinket can be timly.about a month between Fractals,WvW,and Dailies

**Would for example leveling professions like chief and artificer, to get potions and food be more useful to boost my stats? Is this more time-intensive than a ascended gear (to gather resources, craft them), if I want to have a steady supply of those consumables?**
Why not both since both would be advantageous to have. but in the long run Acended gear would pay for its self

the only other stats proggesion after this is get max AR on each piece

and if you want more research on the benifit and dept of stats progession, here is a nifty video on what it looks like with balls to the walls max stats

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion ascended gear is very much worth it.  I recently finished my first full set, down to the infusions.  the stat difference is a lot greater than most people make it out to be. first, there is the base damage of the weapon or defence of the armor adding to your power and armor stats. then you have the stat increases per piece which is small but for all pieces adds up quite a bit, as well as the +5 per piece infusions which adds up to another 80 stat points if youre a wvw player.

Comment: +1 because many people forget about the armor values on ascended armor. I believe these defense points are equivalent to getting 1 toughness per defense.